# React POST request to Django Rest ManyToMany field

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, axios

What I want to do is post a **ListLink** object, which contains **Link** objects, to the database.

The Link objects are added by input field by the user and stored in the state until a request is sent for them to be saved in the database.

I am trying to make a post request to DRF, but I am getting the following response:

```
"Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list."
```

I am using axios to make the request:

**Home.jsx**

```
handleSave = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    return axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/lists/',
        headers: { 
            'Authorization': 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
        },
        data: {
            links: this.state.links,
            name: this.state.listName
        }})
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        });
}
```

This is the state I am using to save the lists in:

```
    this.state = {
        listName: 'Link List',
        listDescription: 'Add description here',
        listURL: '',
        currentLink: 'https://www.example.com',
        links: []
    };
```

Here are my models and serializers:

**LinkList**

```
class LinkList(models.Model):
owner = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    related_name='lists',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
links = models.ManyToManyField(
    Link,
    related_name='linklists')

def __str__(self):
    return "%s - %s" % (self.owner, self.name)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Serializer:

```
class LinkListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="lists-detail")
owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
links = LinkSerializer()

class Meta:
    model = LinkList
    fields = ['url', 'owner', 'name', 'public', 'links']
```

**Link**

```
class Link(models.Model):
link = models.URLField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
    return "%s" % (self.link)
```

Serializer:

```
class LinkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Link
    fields = ['url', 'link']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add `many=True` parameter to `LinkSerializer` but you will need to handle this list yourself (pop `links` attribute and manually create every link object).

```
class LinkListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

    def create(self, validated_data):
        with transaction.atomic(): # optional - ensure that changes will be rolled back on error
            links = validated_data.pop('links', [])
            instance = super().create(validated_data)
            for l in links:
                instance.links.create(link=l)
            return instance
```

Comment: instance.links.add(link=l); add not create :) :)